# Elapsed time of c program in mac through terminal?

Tags: c, macos, terminal

I have my c program and i run it through the terminal. I was wondering how could i know how long does it takes to run the program?
thnxs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time yourcommand.`

For example, `time sleep 2` - this sleeps 2 seconds, then shows you timing statistics.

I get:

```
real    0m2.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

(Your mileage may vary).

Real: how long it actually took, from beginning to end. This is what you would get if you timed it with a stopwatch.

User: this is how much cpu time your program used up (except system time)

Sys: system time - this is how much system CPU time your program took, in system calls - this is things like reading disk etc. (CPU usage only - while waiting for the disk to transfer the data, other programs get to use the CPU).

Note that the CPU time can vary a lot from the real time, in either direction - if your program is multithreaded, it might use all of your CPUs at once; in theory (user+sys)

In the above example, the other extreme - it took over 2 seconds, but the CPU was not involved at all (to within 1 microsecond).